# Convert hex string to unsigned long using strtoul()

Tags: c

I have this silly example program that takes an input value as hex and converts it to an unsigned long integer. After conversion I printf out the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned long int id = 0;

    id = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 16);
    printf("value: %lx\n", id);

    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that running this program with an hex number larger than 31-bit causes the output value to be completely wrong. The upper 32 bits are all converted into (0xf). Shouldnt strtoul() be able to handle numbers up to 2^64? Why are bits >32 garbage? The machine is a X86_64 and actually, the result is also the same with strtoull().

```
$ ./ex 0x7fffffff
value: 7fffffff

$ ./ex 0x80000000
value: ffffffff80000000

$ ./ex 0x3cf180000000
value: ffffffff80000000
```

Comment: If you are compiling with gcc, you really need to (a) use the -Wall option, and (b) read the warnings. http://ideone.com/Z1uz5R

Comment: Thanks for the hint, how can it even work in the first place for smaller numbers when the correct header is not included?

Comment: Undeclared functions are assumed to return int. So you get the low order part of the return value, which is then sign-extended and cast to unsigned long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution works properly for me on my local machine. However, I believe you need to include:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Strtoul is part of stdlib.